# Samples from K probability distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have the following pdf distribution:

$$f(x)=\frac{2b}{\Gamma(\nu)}\left(\frac{bx}{2}\right)K_{\nu-1}(bx)$$
where:
$b$ and $\nu$ are constant and $K_{\nu-1}(.)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind. I need to get samples distribuited starting from this pdf.
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you cancel the 2? Are you asking for code to sample from this distribution?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but the function does not look like a PDF.

Comment: @ablmf: yes I am looking for an algorithm to get samples from this distribution

Comment: @riccardo-alestra I tried to integrate the function in Mathematica and I get infinity.

Comment: @ablmf: this is the pdf of the simplified K distribution used in the simulations of the radar sea clutter

Comment: @ablmf: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-distribution